# How would I go about calculating Zolotarev symbol for large primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How would I go about calculating Zolotarev symbol for large primes?

For example: $$\left(487 \over 1009 \right)$$

Comment: Assuming that "Zolotarev symbol" is another term for Legendre symbol, you can find examples for how to calculate on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Example_of_calculations).

Comment: Zolotarev method uses the sign of a permutation to determine the Jacobi/Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The Zolotarev symbol is the Legendre symbol and is also the Jacobi symbol, this allows you to calculate using a mod function and quadratic reciprocity, for instance (I give you another example so that you can then try with yours) :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(2713 \over 589 \right)(-1)^{\frac{2713-1}{2}\frac{589-1}{2}}$$

Now because $4$ divides $2712=2713-1$ you have that $\frac{2713-1}{2}\frac{589-1}{2}$ is even so :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(2713 \over 589 \right)$$

Now $2713=4\times589+357$$ so that :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(357 \over 589 \right)$$

And then you go on with reciprocity :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(589 \over 357 \right)(-1)^{\frac{589-1}{2}\frac{357-1}{2}}$$

Now because $4$ divides $356=357-1$ you get that :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(589 \over 357 \right)=\left(132 \over 357 \right)$$

It is because $357+232=589$ and then you cannot use the quadratic reciprocity law because $232$ is even but you have $232=4\times 58=2^3\times 29 $ and using multiplicativity of the Jacobi symbol :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=\left(2 \over 357 \right)^3\left(29 \over 357 \right)=\left(2 \over 357 \right)\left(29 \over 357 \right)$$

ow the Jacobi symbol where $2$ is above is known, it is given by the formula :

$$\left(2 \over 357 \right)=(-1)^{\frac{357^2-1}{8}}$$

We have that $357=16\times 22+5$ so $357^2=25=9$ mod $16$ and hence :

$$\left(2 \over 357 \right)=-1$$

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=-\left(29 \over 357 \right)$$

Then you can use, once again quadratic reciprocity :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=-\left(357 \over 29 \right)(-1)^{\frac{357-1}{2}\frac{29-1}{2}}$$

But $4$ divides $356=357-1$ so :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=-\left(357 \over 29 \right)=\left(9 \over 29 \right)=-\left(29 \over 9 \right)(-1)^{\frac{29-1}{2}\frac{9-1}{2}}$$

Now $4$ divides $8=9-1$ so :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=-\left(29 \over 9 \right)=-\left(2 \over 9 \right)=-(-1)^{\frac{9^2-1}{8}}$$

and finally $9^2-1=81-1=80=8\times 10$ so :

$$\left(589 \over 2713 \right)=-1$$

Well if you want to check your result, you should use this calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ and type :

JacobiSymbol(589, 2713);

JacobiSymbol(489, 1009);

Comment: Thanks, but I was concerned with using Zolotarev's method only; where the Legendre symbol is determined by the sign of the permutation upon multiplying by $a$.

Comment: Okay but it verifies the quadratic reciprocity law anyway. Either you calculate this way, or you go concrete saying that for your example you will decompose the multiplication by 489 with 1009 symbols...and then calculate. I don't think you can use this to calculate legendre symbol... The only way I know is this Euclide-like algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with Zolotarev symbol enough we learn two things:

- it is the Legendre symbol
- it obeys Quadratic reciprocity

Before we know that we could look at the map $\color{#999999}{ \times 487 \text{ mod }1009 }$.

Here is one orbit: it is very long.

```
 487,  54,  64, 898, 429,  60, 968, 213, 813, 403, 515, 573, 567, 672, 348
 973, 630,  74, 723, 969, 700, 867, 467, 404,1002, 627, 631, 561, 777,  24
 589, 287, 527, 363, 206, 431,  25,  67, 341, 591, 252, 635, 491, 993, 280
 145, 994, 767, 199,  49, 656, 628, 109, 615, 841, 922,   9, 347, 486, 576
  10, 834, 540, 640, 908, 254, 600, 599, 112,  58,1003, 105, 685, 625, 666
 453, 649, 246, 740, 167, 609, 946, 598, 634,   4, 939, 216, 256, 565, 707
 240, 845, 852, 225, 603,  42, 274, 250, 670, 383, 865, 502, 296, 874, 849
 782, 441, 859, 607, 981, 490, 506, 226,  81,  96, 338, 139,  90, 443, 824
 715, 100, 268, 355, 346,1008, 522, 955, 945, 111, 580, 949,  41, 796, 196
 606, 494, 436, 442, 337, 661,  36, 379, 935, 286,  40, 309, 142, 542, 605
   7, 382, 378, 448, 232, 985, 420, 722, 482, 646, 803, 578, 984, 942, 668
 418, 757, 374, 518,  16, 729, 864,  15, 242, 810, 960, 353, 381, 900, 394
 168,  87,1000, 662, 523, 433, 999, 175, 469, 369, 101, 755, 409, 410, 897
 951,   6, 904, 324, 384, 343, 556, 360, 763, 269, 842, 400,  63, 411, 375
1005,  70, 793, 753, 444, 302, 769, 164, 157, 784, 406, 967, 735, 759, 339
 626, 144, 507, 713, 135, 160, 227, 568, 150, 402,  28, 519, 503, 783, 928
 913, 671, 870, 919, 566, 185, 294, 909, 741, 654, 663,   1
```

It has length 252.  If I start from any other number besides $x_0 = 1$ either:

- cycle is the same as this one
- cycle is another cycle of length 60 disjoint from this one
- cycle is $\{0\}$ -- this is special cycle

All the cycles are even length. And there are $\frac{1008}{252}=4$ of them.  Confusingly, the even-length cycles are *odd*.

$$ (1432) = (14)(132)=(14)(13)(12)$$

and there are an even number of thise.  so that $\frac{487}{1009}=1$.  And $\sqrt{487}_{1009} = \pm 259\dots$